# How to remove a defined part of a string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, string

I have this string: "NT-DOM-NV\MTA"
How can I delete the first part: "NT-DOM-NV"
To have this as result: "MTA"

Answer (score 65, accepted):

you can use this code:

```
str = str.Substring (10); // to remove the first 10 characters.
str = str.Remove (0, 10); // to remove the first 10 characters
str = str.Replace ("NT-DOM-NV\\", ""); // to replace the specific text with blank

//  to delete anything before \

int i = str.IndexOf('\\');
if (i >= 0) str = str.SubString(i+1);
```

Comment: I think the point is for this to work on several different strings, so that he has two strings, and want to remove one from the other.

Comment: @Tassisto, I believe I have more than enough examples to satisfy what you need. If none of them address the issue at hand, please explain again what you need. Hope I have been helpful.

Comment: OP asked for RegEx

Comment: @NitinSawant, the OP changed the question more than 2 years after it has been answered. The original question did not request for RegEx.

Comment: int i = str.IndexOf('\\');
if (i >= 0) str = str.Substring(i+1);

Answer (score 12):

Given that "\" always appear in the string

```
var s = @"NT-DOM-NV\MTA";
var r = s.Substring(s.IndexOf(@"\") + 1);
// r now contains "MTA"
```

Comment: What if the  string is `@"NT-DOM-NV\MTA\ABC\file"` and after splitting `NT-DOM-NV` , I need the first string after split. In this case it should be `MTA`. If I have to split `NT-DOM-NV\MTA` then it should return `ABC`. TIA

Comment: The purpose of the question is to search for and delete a string from the beginning of another string. With your method you can not dynamically identify the location of the string and delete it.

Comment: @zambee The purpose of the question is the get whatever is after the \ char, which is solved in my answer.

Comment: @Mikael Östberg  OK. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

```
string.TrimStart(what_to_cut); // Will remove the what_to_cut from the string as long as the string starts with it.
```

`"asdasdfghj".TrimStart("asd"   );` will result in `"fghj"`.
`"qwertyuiop".TrimStart("qwerty");` will result in `"uiop"`.

---

```
public static System.String CutStart(this System.String s, System.String what)
{
    if (s.StartsWith(what))
        return s.Substring(what.Length);
    else
        return s;
}
```

`"asdasdfghj".CutStart("asd"   );` will now result in `"asdfghj"`.
`"qwertyuiop".CutStart("qwerty");` will still result in `"uiop"`.

Comment: Wired issue. I think many developers don't know that. Anyway, it is really good and clear solution, I replace ALL TrimStart in our application to your CutStart method. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
string string1 = @"NT-DOM-NV\MTA";
string string2 = @"NT-DOM-NV\";

string result = string1.Replace( string2, "" );
```

Comment: string result = string1.Replace( string2, string.Empty );

Answer (score 2):

If there is always only one backslash, use this:

```
string result = yourString.Split('\\').Skip(1).FirstOrDefault();
```

If there can be multiple and you only want to have the last part, use this:

```
string result = yourString.SubString(yourString.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this extension method:

```
public static String RemoveStart(this string s, string text)
{
    return s.Substring(s.IndexOf(s) + text.Length, s.Length - text.Length);
}
```

In your case, you can use it as follows:

```
string source = "NT-DOM-NV\MTA";
string result = source.RemoveStart("NT-DOM-NV\"); // result = "MTA"
```

Note: Do **not** use `TrimStart` method as it might trims one or more characters further ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2836960/665783)).

Answer (score 1):

```
Regex.Replace(@"NT-DOM-NV\MTA", @"(?:[^\\]+\\)?([^\\]+)", "$1")
```

try it [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/r6V026).

Answer (score -1):

```
 string s = @"NT-DOM-NV\MTA";
 s = s.Substring(10,3);
```

Comment: -1: He never specified, that either one of the parts is of fixed length.

Comment: @Daniel: to be fair he has not specified much at all... There may not be a "\" either

Comment: @paolo: You are right. But the assumption that any of those strings is of fixed length maybe would have been correct 30 years ago but not nowadays.

Comment: He gave the exact string as well as the desired result...not sure what the big deal is