# Remove strings till a char is recognized

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to delete parts of the string (first 10 chars) so that I get the serial code of the string without any extra chars. Now, the serial code will always begin after the ":" colon char. So is there a way to specify to delete strings from ":" and before that so that only remaining string would be the serial key?

for example;
string is "MySerials:12e42-23w6z-23w-a23"

final string must be "12e42-23w6z-23w-a23"

I am deleting the strings manually;

```
public string myStr;
 public void Start () {
   myStr = myStr.Substring (10, myStr.Length - 10);
   Debug.Log (myStr);
}
```

Comment: substring and index of. Or split. Or regex. Or skip while.or RangeOperator. There is a ton of way

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove a defined part of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5312211/how-to-remove-a-defined-part-of-a-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the string split function like so:

```
var teststring = "MySerials:12e42-23w6z-23w-a23";
var split = teststring.Split(':');
Console.WriteLine(split[1]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of splitting the string you could look for the first occurrence of ':' and get your result directly:

```
    var input = "MySerials:12e42-23w6z-23w-a23";
    var result = input.Substring(input.IndexOf(':') + 1);
```